# Vue transitions do not work for router-view with reusable component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

So I created component which in which I placed `router-view` only and based on the routes the component changes. Worth noting is that this is second `router-view` and the first one is placed in the `App.vue` component and transition work with that work (they work for all routes except those that are containted with the component below)

**MainComponent.vue**

```
<template>
<transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
     <router-view></router-view>
</transition>
</template>


<style>
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.fade-enter-active {
  transition-delay: .25s;
}

.fade-enter, .fade-leave-active {
  opacity: 0
}
</style>
```

Here is the route setup.

```
{
    path: '/main',
    name: 'main',
    component: () => import('../views/MainComponent.vue'),
    children: [
      {

        path: 'first',
        name: 'first',
        props: { titleName: "First",},
        component: () => import('../components/Component.vue')
      },
      {

        path: 'second',
        name: 'second',
        props: { titleName: "Second"},
        component: () => import('../components/Component.vue')
      },
      {

        path: 'third',
        name: 'third',
        props: { titleName: "Third"},
        component: () => import('../components/Component.vue')
      }
   ]
  }
```

Is there a special setup needed for the transitions to work with reusable component in `<router-view>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you enter a route whose component you are already viewing, by default the component is reused, so there is no DOM transition triggered.  Change your `router-view` to:

```js
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath" />
```

The `key` attribute tells Vue to use a different instance of the component (instead of reusing the existing one) any time the `key` value changes.  With `$route.fullPath`, that will be every time the route changes.